# What are the changed need to do in DB and entity in order to use .hasChanged() method in envers library to get audit records

Tags: java, spring-boot, audit, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to get the audit records from a audit table. in this table, I want to get audit records only if one or two specific columns are changed. to get the audit records i have used the Envers library.only to get the changed records of specific columns, i have used the .hasChanged() method. but when i run it it gives me this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: e_approval_status_MOD of: com.csi.bm.approval.model.entity.Approval_AUD [select e__ from com.csi.bm.approval.model.entity.Approval_AUD e__ where e__.originalId.id = :_p0 and e__.e_approval_status_MOD = :_p1 and e__.e_approval_remark_MOD = :_p2 order by e__.modifiedDate asc]
```

this is the code that i wrote:

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(factory.createEntityManager());
        Set<String> userIds  =  new HashSet<>();
        AuditQuery approvalAudit = reader.createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(Approval.class, true, true)
                .add(AuditEntity.property("id").eq(approvalId))
                .add(AuditEntity.property("e_approval_status").hasChanged())
                .add(AuditEntity.property("e_approval_remark").hasChanged())
                .addOrder(AuditEntity.property("modifiedDate").asc());

        List<Approval> approvalList = approvalAudit.getResultList();
```

In the entity, I already added the @Audited annotation to the entity and added @Audited(withModifiedFlag=true) to the needed attributes.
i can not set the DDL-AUTO: TRUE since we are using Liquibase changeset to alter the tables.
Please let me know, is there any additional changed that i need to do to the entity or the DB level to resolve this issue.

I have changed the audit table columns with the column names mentioned in the error. it won't resolve the issue

Comment: You need to use property names **not** sql column names.

Comment: what did you mean by property names? please explain

Comment: The name of the field in your entity not the mapped column name.